# how to test if TWO input fields are empty?

Tags: jquery

Hi can someone please tell me what wrong with this line  (getting an error...)

```
if ($("input[type=file]").val().length !==0) || $("#book_map_keys").val().length !==0) {
// do something
}
```

As you can probably see, I am testing to see either of these two input field are empty. (they don't both have to be empty)

If you could advise how this should be re-written, I'd be much appreciated.

//Edit:  the error is pointing to the 'OR' pipe character.   Adding those quotes didnt fix it, thanks anyway David

Comment: What is the error that you get? What is the HTML code for those two fields?

Comment: Agree with @IvanPeevski - what error do you see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mismatch parenthesis error

```
// Your line
if ($("input[type=file]").val().length !==0) || $("#book_map_keys").val().length !==0)
// The corrected line
if ($("input[type=file]").val().length !==0 || $("#book_map_keys").val().length !==0)
```